# Find and remove least common element in array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, count

I am trying to find the least common element in an array of integers and remove it, and return the list in the same order.

This is what I have done, but when the list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, my function should return `[]`, but returns `[2, 4]` instead.

```
def check(data):
    for i in data:
        if data.count(i) <= 1:
            data.remove(i)
    return data


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print check(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Deleting items from a list you are iterating over causes you to skip items (ie the next item following each one you delete).

Instead, make a new list containing only the values you want to keep.

```
from collections import Counter

def check(data):
    ctr = Counter(data)
    least = min(ctr.values())
    return [d for d in data if ctr[d] > least]
```

Comment: this is cool, but when I tried, it gave `TypeError: descriptor 'values' of 'dict' object needs an argument`

Comment: it should be `least = min(ctr.values())`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify (especially delete) elements from a list while you are iterating over it.

What happened is:

1. Initially the iterator is at the 1st element, i.e. i = 1
2. Since `d.count(1)` is 1, so you delete 1 from the list.
3. The list is now [2,3,4,5], but the iterator advances to the 2nd element which is now the 3.
4. Since `d.count(3)` is 1 you delete it making the list [2,4,5]
5. The iterator advances to the 3rd element which is now 5.
6. Again you delete the 5 making the list [2,4].

Your algorithm should:

1. Get a count of all elements
2. Find the smallest count.
3. Find the elements with the smallest count.
4. Remove the elements found in step 3 from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check `data.count(i) <= 1`. What happens in this case: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`? `1` and `2` are the least common elements but you will never delete them. Likewise it is a bad idea to mutate a list in a `for` loop.

One thing you can do is use the [`Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

1. Take an appropriate slice of the tail of the `most_common()` method (they entries get *less* frequent as you go down the list, so this is why you take the tail as opposed to the head).
2. Then you can repeatedly search the list for these occurrences and remove them until their are no occurrences left.

Answer (score 0):

one another try:

```
def check(data):
    ctr = Counter(data)
    keys = ctr.keys()
    vals = ctr.values()
    least = []
    m = min(vals)
    for i in range(0,len(vals)):
        if vals[i] == m:
            least.append(keys[i])
    print least

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,1]
result = check(data)
```